# Right approach to develop application with SQL server update using SSIS package

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis

The scenario is:
An console application applies Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime version 10 to execute SSIS package (so no need to deploy the SSIS to sql server), IDE is using Visual studio 2013 & SQL server was 2008 R2.

Now, the company will update the SQL server to 2017 & the application will be force to execute on an instance with SQL server 2017.

This new server didn't contain SQL 2008R2 server SDK thus Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime version 10 threw exception.

It is managed to update Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime to version 13.

The question is:
The development instance didn't install SQL server 2017, thus it didn't contain the reference of Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime version 13 for development.

In this case, should I simply copy the reference to development instance (it works, but not sure if it is the right approach)?
Or it is required to install the SQL server 2017 at the development instance with client tool SDK?

Comment: You must install `Client Tools SDK` as mentioned in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install Microsoft SQL Server Shared feature `Client Tools SDK` even if you don't want to install Database Engine.

Based on the official documentation:

> If you are using the Setup Wizard to install Integration Services, you use a series of pages to specify components and options.
>
> - On the Feature Selection page, under Shared Features, select Integration Services.
> - Under Instance Features, optionally select Database Engine Services to host the SSIS Catalog database, SSISDB, to store, manage, run, and monitor SSIS packages.
> - **To install managed assemblies for Integration Services programming, also under Shared Features, select Client Tools SDK.**

**References**

- [Install Integration Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017#install-integration-services-1)
- [Add Features to an Instance of SQL Server (Setup)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/add-features-to-an-instance-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: interestingly, the OS is unable to initiate the SQL server 2017 setup wizard LOL